# No newpage after \printindex

Tags: page-breaking, indexing

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\index{One}
\newpage

\index{Two}
\newpage

\index{Five}

\printindex

\hfill $\blacksquare$

\end{document}
```

This MWE, newpage after the`\printindex`. And, That I want,

[image]

But I can't do it. How can I do?

Comment: Your example will just show the dot and a page number, but nothing more. You must add some text before `\printindex` comes into action.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, It is working egreg's answer. Question, closed. Thank you for your relationship.

Comment: Well, my comment was rather about that your 'empty' document won't print the index at all ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hook into `\endtheindex`, before it issues `\clearpage` at the end.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeindex

\preto\endtheindex{\par\nobreak\noindent\hfill$\blacksquare$}

\begin{document}

a\index{One}
\newpage

b\index{Two}
\newpage

c\index{Five}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]